# Is there a Java built in equivalent to Kotlin's require function?

Tags: java, kotlin

Kotlin has a [require](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) function which can be used like so (copied from the reference documentation):

```kotlin
fun getIndices(count: Int): List<Int> {
    require(count >= 0) { "Count must be non-negative, was $count" }
    // ...
    return List(count) { it + 1 }
}

// getIndices(-1) // will fail with IllegalArgumentException

println(getIndices(3)) // [1, 2, 3]
```

The function essentially throws an IllegalArgumentException if the value is false.
Obviously this could very easily be implemented in Java - but I was wondering is there something already in the JDK or apache libraries (or any other ubiquitous libraries) which offers a function which does this?

Comment: There are no such built-ins in Java but this looks exactly the same what `Preconditions` are designed for in Google Guava. See more at: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained

Answer (score 5):

You can use `assert` function that is equivalent to the Kotlin `require` method.

```java
assert count >= 0 : "Count must be non-negative, was " + count;
```

[Programming With Assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

JDK disables assert operations by default. If you want to enable assert operations you must define enabled package or class locations with VM options like `-ea:com.example.demo...`

[Enabling and Disabling Assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/6jgp65ikq/index.html)

I prefer Spring Framework's `org.springframework.util.Assert` class, because there are lots of method for validating parameters.

Simpler way:

```java
Assert.isTrue(count >= 0, "Count must be non-negative, was " + count);
```

Lazy way (For better performance and same flow like kotlin `require` function):

```java
Assert.isTrue(count >= 0, () -> "Count must be non-negative, was " + count);
```

[Spring Assert Statements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html)

For Unit tests, you can use, Junit (`org.junit.Assert`) or Jupiter (`org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`) assertion functions.

Comment: One disadvantage of a normal function like the Junit or Spring ones is that they always construct the message string even if the assertion passes; in high-performance systems, the extra temporary objects could have a significant impact.  (That's why the Kotlin function takes a lambda, of course.)

Comment: @gidds There is an overload that accepts a `Supplier` as the second parameter for the Spring `Assert`, so this answer could be improved a bit to match the original `require` behavior.

Comment: The "Programming With Assertions" doc mentions cases where assertions should not be used. Possibly your example falls within one of the cases (Do not use assertions for argument checking in public methods.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `requireNonNull()` in `java.util.Objects` that takes an object reference and checks that for being `null`.

See [the Javadoc here!](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.util.function.Supplier))

But obviously, that is less flexible as the Kotlin version …

Basically, you can write your own version of `require()` like this:

```
public static final void require( final boolean predicate, final Supplier<String> messageSupplier )
{
  if( !predicate ) throw new IllegalArgumentException( messageSupplier.get() );
}
```

(Error handling omitted …)

You can use it like this:

```
…
require( count > 0, () -> String.format( "Count must be non-negative, was %d", count );
…
```

But this requires that `count` is *effectively* `final` (or constant), otherwise it will not compile.

This can be circumvented when creating `require()` like this:

```
public static final void require( final boolean predicate, final Object messageArgument, final Function<Object,String> messageSupplier )
{
  if( !predicate ) throw new IllegalArgumentException( messageSupplier.apply( Objects.toString( messageArgument ) );
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
…
require( count > 0, count, arg -> String.format( "Count must be non-negative, was %s", arg );
…
```

But in case of a primitive type, you have to pay the price for the boxing when calling `require()`.

That in turn can be avoided by having a whole family of `require()` methods, one for each primitive type …

If the main goal is to avoid temporary objects that are not used when the condition of `predicate` is met, I would assume, you should not use inline closures (`() -> …`) but method references (`this::getMessage`) as the `Supplier`/`Function` arguments … but I also think that we are here already on the path of premature optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.4 there is the `assert` keyword in the JDK, which could be used to do something pretty similar. In this case an `AssertionError` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestAsserts {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        int count = -2;

        testCount(count);
    }

    public static void testCount(int count) {
        assert(count >= 0): "Count must be non-negative, was " + count;
    }
}
```

would work the same way.  You get to decide if assertions are enabled or not at runtime.  To run this you'd need to pass `-ea` as a Java command line option.

Note the the exception is a bit different too:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Count must be non-negative, was -2
    at TestAsserts.testCount(TestAsserts.java:12)
    at TestAsserts.main(TestAsserts.java:8)
```

Comment: Despite it looks like a good replacement, it is optional in JVM (you mentioned `-ea` though: _Typically, assertion-checking is enabled during program development and testing, and disabled for deployment, to improve performance._ from JLS), assertion semantics is different and it indicates what must never happen (e.g. switch over all enum values with the default case with no enum); it does not throw `IllegalArgumentException` but an assertion error.

Comment: To add to @fluffy's comment: Errors should not (never?) be caught and handled; obviously this is different for (Runtime)Exceptions. So also from that point of view, `assert` is a bad alternative.

Comment: @tquadrat Yes. _... Again, it is not illegal to use assertions for argument checking on public methods, but it is generally inappropriate. It is intended that AssertionError never be caught, but it is possible to do so, thus the rules for try statements should treat assertions appearing in a try block similarly to the current treatment of throw statements._ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10